# draggable elements with prototype

Tags: javascript, prototypejs, element, draggable, scriptaculous

I am trying to make new draggable elements using prototype. The first element gets added and is draggable, but if I click to add another the second is not draggable. The following is what I have so far:

```
var i = 1;
function addDragElement() {
        var str = i + '.png';
        var attrs = {
            src   :  str,
            class : 'product-tag-image',
            id    : 'product-tag-image' + i,
        };
        var img = new Element('img', attrs);
        $('look-image').insert(img);

        new Draggable(img, 
            { onEnd : function(){
                alert(img.offsetTop + ", " + img.offsetLeft);
            }
        });
        i++;
}
```

Any idea why the first would work but any other elements added would not work?

Answer (score 0):

I got this to work. I replaced `$('look-image').insert(img);` with `$(document.body').insert(img)`;

I didn't have an image handy, so I added some CSS to make your inserted image visible:

```
.product-tag-image {
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    display:block;
    border:1px solid #ff0000    
}
```

Seems fine. Do you get any JS errors? (I did at first because I forgot to include Scriptaculous).

Comment: I have an element with an id of look-image, that is where the draggable item is being inserted. No errors and the first one inserted works fine and I get the top and left values just fine when it is done being dragged. But I need multiple items to be added and make them draggable as well, that is where it breaks, the second one added is not draggable using this.